# Difference between /usr/lib/spark/conf and /etc/spark/conf

Tags: apache-spark

I could see same files at both the locations-

> */usr/lib/spark/conf*

and

> */etc/spark/conf*

**(I am using Cloudera VM)**

Why there are two different locations for the spark configuration ?

How are they related ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default spark 1.6.0 comes with Cloudera VM

```
installation directory of your spark is /usr/lib/spark

configuration directory for your spark is /etc/spark/conf.dist
```

> The /usr/lib/spark/conf is a symbolic link pointing to /etc/spark/conf
>
> /etc/spark/conf is again a symbolic link pointing to /etc/spark/conf.dist (which is your actual configuration directory)

**'/usr/lib/spark/conf'** & **'/etc/spark/conf'** are pointing to the same path eventually

`If you wish to upgrade your spark to a higher version say 2.2.0`

1. Replace the old binaries /usr/lib/spark with new binaries of 2.2.0, and
2. Make sure your /etc/spark/conf points to that new configuration directory

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much nitinr708.

Comment: I am glad it helped you, thanks for acknowledging. Please do share if you face issues during the upgrade..